# Laravel 4 - Options not allowed here in the .htaccess

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-4, public-html

I have installed `Laravel 4` on my `public_html` folder locally, and I can access its `public` folder when declaring a `vhost` pointing to it, through the `vhost url`.

But, when I try to access `Laravel` public folder through its parent folders, I get an error in apache logs (`error_log`): `$LARAVEL_HOME/public/.htaccess`: Options not allowed here. Even if there is a `AllowOverride All` in `$VHOST_CONF/site`.

The first line in the .htaccess (`Options Multiviews`), is causing this error when I delete it, or put it in `$VHOST_CONF/site`, it works.

So, How do I do to I access through the hierarchy, without modifying the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: you should never be accessing Laravel root folder "publically". The only folder you should every access "publically" is public

Comment: I know but is it what was causing this error?

Comment: The easiest thing (and probably the most secure) would be to install Laravel 4 below your `public_html`, delete your `public_html` folder and create a symlink `ln -s public public_html`.

Comment: `FollowSymLink` must activated in Apache `Httpd`?

Answer (score 5):

In the Apache configuration file for the website set AllowOverride to AllowOverride All similar to the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        # changed from None to All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I think the best method to use (as suggested by @evolve) is to put only /public folder in `www` (public_html) folder.

Comment: This fixed it for me, but only when I realised it was `sites-available/default` (`000-default.conf` in Ubuntu 13) that needed editing, and not the main `apache2.conf`.

Comment: Apache 2.4.41 complains about Order.